# Find list of class in list of class with lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a class Synchronize

```
internal sealed class Synchronize
{
    internal _File File { get; set; } = new _File();
    internal _Log Log { get; set; } = new _Log();

    internal sealed class _File
    {
        internal string Folder { get; set; }
        internal string Name { get; set; }
        internal string Extention { get; set; }
        internal string Create_Date_Time { get; set; }
        internal long Size { get; set; }
        internal int RecordCount { get; set; }
    }

    internal sealed class _Log
    {
        internal string Folder { get; set; }
        internal string Name { get; set; }
        internal string Extention { get; set; }
        internal string CreateDateTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have another class Migrate

```
internal sealed class Migrate
{
    internal string FileFolder { get; set; }
    internal string FileName { get; set; }
    internal int RecordCount { get; set; }
    internal bool CanMigrate { get; set; } = false;
}
```

I have

```
List<Synchronize> synchronize
```

and

```
List<Migrate> migrate
```

synchronize has 100+ list items, but migrate has 1+ list items.

Is there a way using a lambda expression to find all item in synchronize that exist in migrate by means of searching for migrate.FileFolder && migrate.FileName && migrate.RecordCount?

I know how to do a lambda search on synchronize by way of iterating though migrate, but I'm trying to avoid the iteration and trying to learn more lambda, it is so cool when you begin to grasp it  :)

Comment: Please don't use verbs as class names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use

```
var results = synchronize.Where(s => migrate.Any(m => /* compare here */));
```

But I'd probably use a join:

```
var results = from s in synchronize
              join m in migrate
              on new { s.File.Folder, s.File.Name, s.File.RecordCount }
              equals new { Folder = m.FileFolder, Name = m.FileName, m.RecordCount }
              select s;
```

Or in lambda syntax:

```
var results = synchronize.Join(migrate,
    s => new { s.File.Folder, s.File.Name, s.File.RecordCount },
    m => new { Folder = m.FileFolder, Name = m.FileName, m.RecordCount },
    (m, s) => s);
```

Comment: Why would you suggest the join? What is the difference between using the join and not using the join; do the results differ or it is purely for optimization?

Comment: @Bazïnga: It's partly optimization if there end up being a lot of entries in `migrate`, and partly because it feels logically like you're performing a join. But the `Where` approach will certainly work too.

Comment: thanks a million, works like a charm! I'm starting to want to put lambda all over the place now :D

Comment: This approach creates the new objects which is not necessary, but the performance diff is so small that it may be ignored

Comment: @DaisyShipton I tried the lambda join this morning, the last one of your examples, but I get error "The type arguments for method Enumerable.Join xxxxxxx cannot be inferred from the usage". Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. I have NO idea what this means!?

Comment: @Bazïnga: I've just corrected a mistake from `s.RecordCount` to `s.File.RecordCount` and it compiles for me using the definitions you've provided. Could you create a gist or dotnetfiddle showing a complete example with it failing?

Comment: @DaisyShipton due to the nature of the project I cannot divulge more detail. I will use the .Where approach for now and try and figure out the .Join as I go along. Once again thanks for your brilliant help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Bazïnga: You don't need to show anything confidential - just enough to reproduce the problem. Look for any differences between what you've already shown (which works with the code I've given) and your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a combination of `Where` and `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var result = synchronize.Where(s => migrate.FirstOrDefault(m => m.FileFolder == s.File.Folder && m.FileName == s.File.Name && m.RecordCount == s.File.RecordCount) != null);
```

Or using `Any`:

```
var result = synchronize.Where(s => migrate.Any(m => m.FileFolder == s.File.Folder && m.FileName == s.File.Name && m.RecordCount == s.File.RecordCount));
```

Comment: Your first version is awful. Also, I'd recommend adding in some linefeeds in your code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using this:

```
var synchronize = new List<Synchronize>();
//fill synchronize    
var migrate = new List<Migrate>();
//fill migrate

var result = synchronize
    .Where(s => migrate.Exists(m => m.FileFolder == s.File?.Folder
                                    && m.FileName == s.File?.Name
                                    && m.RecordCount == s.File?.RecordCount)
    .ToList();
```

As a DavidG mentioned in comments, it is better to use Extension method `Any` working on any Enumerable.

`Exists` works only on `List`.

```
result = synchronize
    .Where(s => migrate.Any(m => m.FileFolder == s.File?.Folder
                                    && m.FileName == s.File?.Name
                                    && m.RecordCount == s.File?.RecordCount))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I'd avoid using `Exists()` as it only works with `List<T>`, stick with `Any()`

Comment: Yes, I saw that he has a Lists so I used Exists but it can be changed easily

Comment: The point is that it's better to get used to using a method that will work on any enumerable, makes a good habit.