# Copy value of matching id

Tags: c#

First, read the Class code below. There you will find a property called- CommonId which is common in Item class and ItemGallery and both has matching int value. Now check the Program class which is the main console program. Here I am adding some data to both classes to make an example. On the bottom of main program class, I am trying to loop through each Item and find its commonId matching with ItemGallery commonId if that commonId matched then in ItemGallery ItemId will be copied from its matching Item Id. The main goal is- Just take the copy from Item class Id to ItemGallery ItemId which has matching commonId. How to do that? I already tried foreach like bellow but this not the correct way.

Main Program Class:

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<Item> MyItemList = new List<Item>();
            MyItemList.Add(new Item {
                CommonId = 502,
                Id = 3,
                Link = "some string1"
            });

            MyItemList.Add(new Item {
                CommonId = 502,
                Id = 4,
                Link = "some string2"
            });

            MyItemList.Add(new Item {
                CommonId = 502,
                Id = 5,
                Link = "some string3"
            });

            MyItemList.Add(new Item {
                CommonId = 506,
                Id = 6,
                Link = "some string4"
            });

            List<ItemGallery> MyitemGalleries = new List<ItemGallery>();
            MyitemGalleries.Add(new ItemGallery {
                CommonId = 502,
                Link = "",
            });
            MyitemGalleries.Add(new ItemGallery {
                CommonId = 502,
                Link = "",
            });
            MyitemGalleries.Add(new ItemGallery {
                CommonId = 502,
                Link = "",
            });

            foreach (var _MyItemList in MyItemList) {
                MyitemGalleries.FirstOrDefault().ItemId = _MyItemList.Where(x => x.CommonId == MyitemGalleries.CommonId).FirstOrDefault().Id;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Class:

```
class Item {
    public int Id { get; set; }//this id need to set to ItemGallery ItemId matching their CommonId
    public int CommonId { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}

class ItemGallery {
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int CommonId { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not sure that code will even compile.  `MyitemGalleries.CommonId` is invalid, as `MyitemGalleries` is of type `List<ItemGallery>` - `CommonId` is an invalid property.

Comment: I do not understand. Invalid property mean?

Comment: Unrelated tip 1: `FirstOrDefault().ItemId` and `FirstOrDefault().Id` are *code smells*, because if the `OrDefault` happens then you will get a NullReferenceException. So if you expect there to be a match, use `First()`, or if it's possible that there will not be one then you need `?` after the method.

Comment: Unrelated tip 2: `.Where(x => x.CommonId == MyitemGalleries.CommonId).FirstOrDefault()` can be written more simply as  `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CommonId == MyitemGalleries.CommonId)`. (And tip 1 still applies, as it always will).

Comment: This looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025111, just with simpler IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you and disregarding any other problems, there are few ways to do this. However, a simple `foreach` and `FirstOrDefault` should do

```
foreach (var gallery in MyitemGalleries) 
{
    var item = _MyItemList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CommonId == gallery.CommonId);
    // note if there are none we choose not to do anything, or grab the first
    if(item == null)
       continue;

    gallery.ItemId = item.Id;
}
```